# Get default value from JOIN query if join field value doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `customers` and `reviews`. The structure is like this:

customers:-

```
|---------------------------------|
|  id  |         name             |
|---------------------------------|
|   1  |       Thutmekri          |
|---------------------------------|
|   3  |        Conan             |
|---------------------------------|
```

reviews:-

```
|-------------------------------------------|
|   id   |   business_id  |    customer_id  |
|-------------------------------------------|
|   1    |       1        |        1        |
|-------------------------------------------|
|   2    |       1        |        2        |
|-------------------------------------------|
|   3    |       1        |        3        |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

`customer_id` of `reviews` is `id` of `customer`.

The join query,

```
SELECT customers.name, reviews.id as review_id 
FROM customers, reviews 
WHERE customers.id = reviews.customer_id
```

returns the dataset like this:-

```
|----------------------------------|
|    review_id  |      name        |
|----------------------------------|
|       1       |      Thutmekri   |
|----------------------------------|
|       3       |      Conan       |
|----------------------------------|
```

But I want it to return:-

```
|----------------------------------|
|    review_id  |      name        |
|----------------------------------|
|       1       |      Thutmekri   |
|----------------------------------|
|       2       |      N/A         |
|----------------------------------|
|       3       |      Conan       |
|----------------------------------|
```

For customer_id in reviews, which doesn't have any data in customers table, I want 'N/A' to be displayed. How can I do it?

The following query also didn't help

```
SELECT reviews.id as review_id, COALESCE( name, 'N/A' )
FROM customers, reviews
WHERE customers.id = reviews.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join and switch the order of the tables in the join:

```
SELECT
    r.id AS review_id,
    COALESCE(c.name, 'N/A') AS name
FROM reviews r
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.id = r.customer_id;
```

### SQLFiddle

Comment: Please remove additional quote (') from you query near semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT r.id  as review_id, COALESCE( c.name, 'N/A' ) FROM reviews r
LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id = r.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Right outer join to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    reviews.id as review_id,
    COALESCE(name, 'N/A' )
FROM customers
RIGHT JOIN reviews
    ON customers.id = reviews.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

SELECT
     R.id AS review_id,
     COALESCE(C.name, 'N/A') AS name FROM reviews R LEFT JOIN customers C  ON R.customer_id = C.id ;